# Converting text box input(html page) into a dictionary in flask(Python)

Tags: python, html, dictionary, flask

I am using `html` and `flask`. If a user enters a value with key in text box, how do I convert that into a dictionary?

Input :

```
'x':df['region'], 'y':df['age'], 'z': df['smoker']
```

Output:

```
{'x':df['region'], 'y':df['age'], 'z': df['smoker']}
```

Comment: I don't understand - you already have dictionary in input.

Comment: you have to better describe it. OR put minimal working code which shows how you get `input`. Is this single string or something different? For string you may use `eval(text)` - eventually it may need `eval( "{" + text + "}" )`. But it can be dangerous because someone can put code which will delete all your files. It would be safer to get only text `"x:region,y:age,z:smoker"` and split it. using `split(",")` and `split(":")`

Comment: yes, how do I split for single line string/text?

Comment: if you have string then use string functions like `split()`, slicing `[start:end]`, `replace()`, etc. Eventually use `regex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have it as string

```
query = "'x':df['region'], 'y':df['age'], 'z': df['smoker']"
```

then you could use `eval()` to convert it

```
data = eval("{" + query + "}")
```

Maybe it is not safe but it is fast and easy.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
         'region': [1,2,3],
         'age':    [4,5,6],
         'smoker': [7,8,9],
         'other':  ['A','B','C'],
     })

query = "'x':df['region'], 'y':df['age'], 'z': df['smoker']"

data  = eval("{" + query + "}")

print(data)
```

Comment: you can mark my answer as accepter and few minutes later you can upvote it.